# Drawing a line from a dot to dot (Point to Point) on Form MouseDown

Tags: c#, point

I've been working days on a program that draws a grid of dots, and I had to start all over again several times because of a bad approach / to complicated. I've come to a point now where I have to draw a line from a clicked dot (point) to a second clicked dot (point) on the form.
Seriously I've been spending hours even days of my time searching for the right approach.
As for now I only managed to get a line drawn from a point on the form to another point on the form on random clicks...
Could someone please help get the code done, its just frustrating me how I don't have any progress after all attempts of drawing a grid of dots..
So what I want to do is "draw a line from a clicked dot (point) to a second clicked dot (point) on the form".

See below of my code:

**Form1.cs:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private GridDrawing drawing;

    private Point point1;
    private Point point2;
    List<Point> p1List = new List<Point>(); //Temp
    List<Point> p2List = new List<Point>(); //Temp

    //True if point1 must be updated
    //False if point2 must be updated
    private bool firstPoint = true;

    private int sizeOfDot;
    private int rows;
    private int columns;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sizeOfDot = 10;     //The size of the dot
        rows = 6;           //The amount of rows for the matrix
        columns = 8;        //The amount of columns for the matrix
    }

    private void Form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, ClientRectangle);   //Fill the form in white
        drawing = new GridDrawing(this, rows, columns);             //Control, Rows, Columns

        foreach (var piece in drawing.Pieces)                           //Draws all the dots
        {
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, (piece.Dot.X - sizeOfDot / 2),
                (piece.Dot.Y - sizeOfDot / 2), sizeOfDot, sizeOfDot);   //Draws the dot
        }

        using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < p1List.Count; i++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, p1List[i], p2List[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    private void startToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (firstPoint)             //Update point1 or point2
        {
            //Point 1
            point1.X = e.X;
            point1.Y = e.Y;
        }
        else
        {
            //Point 2
            point2.X = e.X;
            point2.Y = e.Y;

            p1List.Add(point1);
            p2List.Add(point2);
        }
        firstPoint = !firstPoint;   //Change the bool value
        Invalidate();               //Redraw
    }

    private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

**GridDrawing.cs:**

```
public class GridDrawing
{
    private int columns;
    private int rows;
    private List<GridPiece> pieces;
    private Point dot;

    //private Point point1; //point1 to start drawing line from
    //private Point point2; //point2 to end drawing line from

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a grid
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ctrl"></param>
    /// <param name="rows"></param>
    /// <param name="columns"></param>
    /// <param name="sizeOfDot"></param>
    public GridDrawing(Control ctrl, int rows, int columns)
    {
        this.rows = rows;               // The amount of rows in the matrix.
        this.columns = columns;         // The amount of columns in the matrix.

        this.pieces = new List<GridPiece>();                // Initializes the List GridPieces

        int xOffset = (int)ctrl.ClientRectangle.Width / (columns + 1);  // FP offset for X
        int yOffset = (int)ctrl.ClientRectangle.Height / (rows + 1);    // FP offset for Y

        //Generate the dots
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)          //Matrix with 6 rows                      
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)   //Matrix with 8 columns
            {
                dot = new Point((j + 1) * xOffset, (i + 1) * yOffset);  // Center of the dot
                GridPiece p = new GridPiece(dot);  // Creates a piece
                pieces.Add(p);                     // Puts the piece that has to be drawn in the List<GridPiece>pieces
            }
        }
    }

    public List<GridPiece> Pieces   //Property List<GridPiece>pieces
    {
        get { return this.pieces; }
    }

    public Point Dot                //Property Point dot
    {
        get { return this.dot; }
    }
}
```

**GridPiece.cs:**

```
public class GridPiece
{
    private Point dot;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor of GriedPiece
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bmpPic"></param>
    /// <param name="position"></param>
    public GridPiece(Point dot)
    {
        this.dot = dot;
    }

    public Point Dot
    {
        get { return dot; }
    }
}
```

Here's an example how I'm trying to make it look like
[image: EXAMPLE]

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Just curious, is it a homework assignment?

Comment: Thanks for reading Anders, and its a small part of a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do this. add following code

```
  public class Line
{
    public float X1 { get; set; }
    public float X2 { get; set; }
    public float Y1 { get; set; }
    public float Y2 { get; set; }
}


public sealed class Grid : Panel
{
    readonly DotDrawing drawing = new DotDrawing();
    private List<Line> Markers { get; set; }

    public Grid()
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        Markers = new List<Line>();
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (Line line in Markers)
        {
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black))
            {
                pen.Width = 2;
                e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, line.X1, line.Y1, line.X2, line.Y2);
            }
        }drawing.Render(e.Graphics);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    private Dot lastDot;
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        var x = this.drawing.GetDotFromPoint(e.Location);
        if (x != null)
        {
            lastDot = x;

        }
        else
        {
            lastDot = null;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        var x = this.drawing.GetDotFromPoint(e.Location);
        if (x != null)
        {
            Line line = new Line();
            line.X1 = lastDot.Center.X;
            line.Y1 = lastDot.Center.Y;

            line.X2 = x.Center.X;
            line.Y2 = x.Center.Y;
            this.Markers.Add(line);
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

}
public class Dot
{
    public PointF Location { get; set; }
    public int Radius { get; set; }
    public PointF Center
    {
        get
        {
            return new PointF(this.Bounds.Left + (float)this.Radius,
                this.Bounds.Top + (float)this.Radius);
        }
    }
    public RectangleF Bounds
    {
        get
        {
            return new RectangleF(Location, new SizeF(2 * Radius, 2 * Radius));
        }
    }

    public Dot()
    {
        Radius = 5;
    }
}
public class DotDrawing
{
    private List<Dot> Dots { get; set; }
    public int RowCount { get; set; }
    public int ColumnCount { get; set; }
    public int ColumnSpacing { get; set; }
    public int RowSpacing { get; set; }
    public int DotRadius { get; set; }

    public DotDrawing()
    {
        Dots = new List<Dot>();
        DotRadius = 10;
        ColumnCount = 15;
        RowCount = 25;
        this.RowSpacing = 30;
        this.ColumnSpacing = 30;
    }
    public void Render(Graphics g)
    {
        this.Dots.Clear();
        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                {
                    Dot dot = new Dot();
                    dot.Location = new PointF(x, y);
                    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#009aff")))
                    {
                        g.FillEllipse(brush, dot.Location.X, dot.Location.Y, DotRadius, DotRadius);

                    }

                    x += (DotRadius + ColumnSpacing);
                    Dots.Add(dot);
                }
            }
            x = 0;
            y += (DotRadius + this.RowSpacing);
        }
    }

    public Dot GetDotFromPoint(PointF point)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Dots.Count; i++)
        {

            RectangleF rect = this.Dots[i].Bounds;
            rect.Inflate(new SizeF(3, 3));
            Region region = new Region(rect);
            if (region.IsVisible(point))
            {
                return this.Dots[i];
            }


        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Drag the Grid from the tool box.
Mouse Click on any of the dots without releasing it point to  another grid you'll see the effect.

Comment: Thank you so much Int3 for your time and your help. I never noticed the Grid .NET Component in my Toolbox, is it something that I created with your code? I'm new to the C# world and I kinda feel stupid for asking that. I also would like to know if its possible to achieve the same thing with my code as with your code. Because when I see your code (even if it works) I still have question marks above my head. I never worked with Region or Floating Rectangle.

Comment: Curious why not `class Line { PointF P1; PointF P2 }` which would simplify the code?